# Copy menu is greyed out in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-office, copy-paste

I'm running Word for Mac 2011 and the Copy menu is greyed out. Command-C works. This is on OS X 10.11 El Capitan. My mother-in-law has the same problem and she's on 10.9 Mavericks (I think).

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. Go to:

View > Toolbars > Customize Toolbars and Menus...

Click on Menu Bar row and select Reset

Quit Word and relaunch